# Setting an image after retrieving the result of a post request takes 17s

Tags: ios, uiimageview, objective-c-blocks, nsurlsession

I am making a post request to the server that returns a string, that says if a user exist or not with that nickname, the post notification works flawless and prints out the returned result in the under 1s from inside the completion handler, but it takes additional 17 to 20 to set the image based on the returned result...

Here is the code that I am using:

```
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField{
    // for each textfield selected checkl previous text field formating

    if (textField == registerEmailAddressTextField)
    {

        //check if nickname is at least 6 charactes

        if (registerNicknameTextField.text.length < 6) {
            NSLog(@"EMIAL TEXT FIELD");
            [registerNicknameCheckmarkLabel setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"wrong_checkmark.png"]];

        }else{
            NSLog(@"checking nickname");
            //check if nickname exists or not

            NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"myURL"];


            //Create the session with custom configuration
            NSURLSessionConfiguration *sessionConfiguration = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];

            NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:sessionConfiguration];


            NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url];
            request.HTTPMethod = @"POST";



            NSError *error = nil;
            NSString* str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"username=%@", registerNicknameTextField.text];
            NSData* jsonData = [str dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

            [request setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", (int)registerNicknameTextField.text.length] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
            if (!error) {

                NSURLSessionUploadTask *uploadTask = [session uploadTaskWithRequest:request
                                                                           fromData:jsonData completionHandler:^(NSData *data,NSURLResponse *response,NSError *error) {


                                                                               NSString *responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
                                                                               NSString* result2 = [responseString stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
                                                                               NSString *secondString = [result2 stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];
                                                                               if ([secondString isEqualToString:@"exist"]) {
                                                                                   NSLog(@"nickname allready exists");
                                                                                   [registerNicknameCheckmarkLabel setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"wrong_checkmark.png"]];
                                                                               }else{
                                                                                   [registerNicknameCheckmarkLabel setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"correct_checkmark.png"]];
                                                                                   NSLog(@"nickname doesn't exists");
                                                                               }
                                                                           }];


                [uploadTask resume];
            }

        }




    }
}
```

I even tried with no success to force refresh the screen by using these code:

```
dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW,
                                        (int64_t)(0.005 * NSEC_PER_SEC));
dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void) {
    [self.view setNeedsDisplay];
});
```

Comment: You should try dispatching your `setImage:` calls onto the main thread.  I think the `completionHandler` gets called on a background queue.

Comment: Don't make UI changes anywhere except the main thread. Try using GCD to retrieve the main thread and run your code on that. It might not change anything, but it is good practice. Out of curiosity how big is the image?

Comment: If I understand correctly 'nickname allready exists' is logged quickly, but the image then takes some time to actually appear -- i.e. the networking code all completes but then it takes ~16s from calling `
                                                                               [registerNicknameCheckmarkLabel setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"wrong_checkmark.png"]];` to seeing the image appear.. is that right?

Answer (score 0):

So as suggested by @dan I putted everything on the main queue:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{                                                                                                     
if ([secondString isEqualToString:@"exist"]) {                                                                                               
[registerNicknameCheckmarkLabel setImage:[UIImage 
imageNamed:@"wrong_checkmark.png"]];                                                                                           
}else{                                                                                               
[registerNicknameCheckmarkLabel setImage:[UIImage 
imageNamed:@"correct_checkmark.png"]];                                                                                           
}                                                                        
});
```